# Java Operators - how println using ++ works

Tags: java

Trying to understand why the x++ computes after print, while x=x+1 computes before print:

```
    int x = 3;
    System.out.println("Ans: " + (x++));
    System.out.println("Ans: " + (x=x+1));

    Ans: 3
    Ans: 5
```

Comment: Why you asked this question

Comment: `x++` is post-increment. It evaluates to the old value of `x` before increasing it by one. `x=(x+1)` is equivalent to pre-increment (`++x`) where x is first increased by one and then the expression evaluates to the new value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that is how it is defined. `x++` is post-increment, if you use `++x` it is pre-increment, like `x=x+1`.

More information in the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) (emphasis mine):

> The increment/decrement operators can be applied before (prefix) or after (postfix) the operand. The code `result++;` and `++result;` will both end in result being incremented by one. The only difference is that the prefix version (`++result`) evaluates to the incremented value, whereas the postfix version (`result++`) evaluates to the original value. If you are just performing a simple increment/decrement, it doesn't really matter which version you choose. **But if you use this operator in part of a larger expression, the one that you choose may make a significant difference.**